# Aframe definir mi propio "marker" de un archivo .patt

Tags: realidad-aumentada

estoy intentando crear un sitio móvil que use la cámara para mostrar realidad aumentada. Lo que necesito es que crear mi propio "" de un archivo .patt que tengo. O sea, que debo agregar, cambiar o quitar de la etiqueta "" para agregar mi archivo y no el preset de "hiro".

Este es el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <charset="UTF-8">
    
            <!-- script de A-Frane version1 1.0.0 -->
            <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
            <!-- script de AR.JS con soporte de marker + location -->
            <script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
        </head>
    
        <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
            <a-scene embedded arjs>
                <a-marker preset="hiro">
                    <a-sphere position="0 0 0" radius="0.6" color="green"></a-sphere>
                </a-marker>
            <a-entity camera></a-entity>
            </a-scene>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Puede a través de este sitio:

https://ar-js-org.github.io/studio/pages/marker/index.html

Crear mi propio marcador como también lo que se visualizará en la realidad aumentada.

Ojalá les sirva, como también poder saber como agregar más marcadores.

Paso un código de ejemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/studio-backend/master/src/modules/marker/tools/gesture-detector.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/studio-backend/master/src/modules/marker/tools/gesture-handler.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
  <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" loading-screen="enabled: false;" arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;" id="scene" embedded gesture-detector>
    <a-marker id="animated-marker" type="pattern" preset="custom" url="assets/pattern-Foto1.patt" raycaster="objects: .clickable" emitevents="true" cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;" id="markerA">
      <a-image src="assets/txt1.png" scale="1 1 1" class="clickable" rotation="-90 0 0" gesture-handler></a-image>>
    </a-marker>
    <a-marker id="animated-marker" type="pattern" preset="custom" url="assets/pattern-Foto2.patt" raycaster="objects: .clickable" emitevents="true" cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;" id="markerA">
      <a-image src="assets/txt2.png" scale="1 1 1" class="clickable" rotation="-90 0 0" gesture-handler></a-image>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```